# Solve the exponential-trigonometry equation

Tags: trigonometry

I have the problem
$$
3^{\sin x} \cdot 3^{\sin 2x} \cdot 3^{\sin 3x} \cdot \ldots = 3.
$$

I’ve converted it to
$$
\sin x + \sin 2x + \sin 3x + \ldots = 1,
$$
but what should I do next?

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE. Please write your questions using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). I have edited your question this time, as questions will be better received with the right formatting. It's also great that you've shown at least one step.

Comment: It might be helpful for you to view [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/17966/how-can-we-sum-up-sin-and-cos-series-when-the-angles-are-in-arithmetic-pro) and see if you can answer your question then.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Use that for your sum is hold:
$$\sum_{i=1}^{n}\sin(ix)=\csc \left(\frac{x}{2}\right) \sin \left(\frac{n
   x}{2}\right) \sin \left(\frac{1}{2} (n+1)
   x\right)$$